# Apache: /cgi-bin/my.cgi was not found on this server

Tags: apache, cgi, osx-server

I'm struggling to get my server to recognize cgi-bin in a URL.

If I place my cgi script in any site's root folder, it works perfectly without including cgi-bin in the URL. So my server is processing cgi correctly. If I attempt to use any cgi-bin configuration, it results in a 404 error.

I'm running it on a Mac server with OS 10.10. Ideally I would like to locate the cgi script in /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables and address it as cgi-bin: Some.com/cgi-bin/my.cgi?yaddayadda .

In pursuit of that, I've edited Apache's httpd.conf file. It was already set with that as the path but resulted in the 404. Currently httpd.conf is:

```
# "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .wsgi
</Directory>

# To allow CGI program execution for any file ending in .cgi in 
# users' directories, you can use the following configuration.

#ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/*
#  <Directory /home/*>
#      Options +ExecCGI
#      AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
#  </Directory>

# If you wish designate a cgi-bin subdirectory of a user's directory
# where everything will be treated as a CGI program, you can use the following.
# ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/cgi-bin/
# <Directory /home/cgi-bin>
#      AllowOverride None
#       Options +ExecCGI
#       AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
#   </Directory>
```

As this shows, I've tried using a cgi-bin folder within the site folders as well. I've also added the .wsgi handler and gotten the same results with a Python Hello World. It too works from the root folder of any site. I just can't get it to refer to what I want as the cgi-bin. Even if I nest a cgi-bin folder inside CGI-Executables. I always get "The requested URL /cgi-bin/my.cgi was not found on this server."

I do restart Apache after every edit and have rebooted the whole machine several times. Nothing changes.

Unless I'm doing something wrong in my edits above, it's almost as if Apache is ignoring the httpd.conf. I don't know how to confirm that the file is being read when Apache starts. There is no other httpd.conf file located anywhere that should matter and those typically bear names that suggest they're from the past: httpd.conf.pre-update and httpd.conf-previous.

My best guess is that I have some error in the path or aliased path. I have tried every variation on them that I can come up with. The full path to my desired cgi-bin is: Server HD2/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables. Or a cgi-bin folder within a site's root folder would be: Server HD2/Library/WebServer/Documents/TheSite/cgi-bin

I've also checked for any .htaccess files that could be overriding my edits. None found.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you been to `/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/` and done a `chmod 755 *?

Comment: I hadn't but have now with no change. If it were permissions I'd get a Forbidden error though instead of a 404 - wouldn't I?